# Make a kernel module loadable at run time

Tags: c, compilation, makefile, freebsd, kernel-module

I am trying to make a kernel module loadable on run time. i.e remove it from normal makefile tree compilation, compile it separately and load it via kldload

My configuration:
* I am using freebsd 9.0 stable
* make buildkernel with a standard Makefile

As of now I have no clue how to start with this, googled a bit but no success so far.
So how do I remove my kernel module "module_test" from Makefile and start with separately.
Do i need to change any thing from code also apart from makefiles ?

Any pointers to start of with.

Answer (score 0):

There are several modules in the ports collection. Take a look at their buildsystems.

The portnames usually ends in -kmod;  E.g: audio/aureal-kmod, comms/hso-kmod comms/ib-kmod comms/uhso-kmod etc.